# Force Firefox mailto with webmail to open new tab

Tags: firefox, email, gmail, mailto

I have successfully configured Firefox (43.0.4) to open `mailto` links in Gmail using [Mozilla's instructions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-program-used-open-email-links).

`mailto` now triggers a new Gmail Compose however this uses the current tab and navigates away from the current page.

This is particularly frustrating in [Feedly](https://feedly.com) when I want to send an article and then continue reading the next in my feed - I now have to navigate `Back` which reloads Feeldy, loosing the thread of where I was in my article list.

`ctrl`-clicking a `mailto` link does not work.

Is there any way to force Firefox to open `mailto` in a new tab or new window?

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the email address, then click 'open-in-a-new-tab'.  Works for me.  I hope it works for you.

Comment: It doesn't work in Feedly. As soon as you right click it navigates to the new email compose

Comment: does it work for you on other sites?  
If you are on a mac, you could try ⌘-click, or whatever the equivalent on your system is.